# Achieving complex objects without sculpting

Tags: modeling, objects, extrude

I am following a tutorial video titled [Fantasy Elven House - Speed Modeling In Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL3CSrerZwE&t), but since a couple of days I've been stuck at [5:05](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL3CSrerZwE&t=307s).

I understand that he is using Mirror and Subdivision modifiers, but how is he doing that? Does he Extrude? And if he does, how? How he is able to achieve fluid manipulation with objects using Extrude?

When I tried to do the same thing with the Extrude tool I do not get that control over my object, and my shape looks unnatural.
And although the keys he uses are displayed, I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He's extruding, either with <kbd>E</kbd> or select an edge and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>right click</kbd> (*Extrude to 3D Cursor*):

[image]

Comment: Yes this is it, although it only works with ctrl + r click ,i guess rest of it is just practice ,Thanks for answer ,it really helped :)